# identity Server - Configuring CORS for bearer options

Tags: asp.net-web-api, cors, identityserver3

I am testing the jquery ajax calls to the API server from a different domain. Unfortunately I am getting an OPTIONS error. Here is my request code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://localhost:44356/api/Default/",
    headers: {
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + user.access_token
    },
    success: function (res) {
        logAjaxResult(res);
    },
    error: function() {
        logAjaxResult('Error');
    }
}))
```

Which gives

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://localhost:44356/api/Default/. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405.
```

Normally this is an easy fix - I install Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors, set up a provider and allow OPTIONS through always. I can see how I would normally do this on the Identity Server box too as there is a CorsProvider you can register up. My issue however is on the API box I am using IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions and I see no CORs options. When I try to set up the WebAPI.cors provider though I get an error saying there are multiple origins set on the server to allow. This indicates to me (correct me if I'm wrong) that the WebApi box has somehow got the CORs settings from my identity server box that is registered as it's authority. Is this right?

How do I configure to allow pre-flight requests with app.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication(options)?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

This issue was resolved when I found the documentation uses

```
Microsoft.Owin.Cors
```

I was using the package

```
Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors
```